# may you explain this algorithm of calculate to average for noise

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on embedded programming with written code by other people.

this algorithm be used in calculate average for mic and accelerometer

```
      sound_value_Avg = 0;
      sound_value = 0;
      memset((char *)soundRaw, 0x00, SOUND_COUNT*2);
    
      for(int i2=0; i2 < SOUND_COUNT; i2++)
      {
        soundRaw[i2] = analogRead(PIN_ANALOG_IN);
        if (i2 == 0)
        {
          sound_value_Avg = soundRaw[i2];
        }
        else
        {
          sound_value_Avg = (sound_value_Avg + soundRaw[i2]) / 2;
        }
      }
    
      sound_value = sound_value_Avg;
```

acceleromter is similar to this

```
n1=p1

(n2+p1)/2 = p2

(n3+p2)/2 = p3

(n4+p3)/2 = p4

...

avg(n1~nx)=px
```

it not seems to be correct.

can someone explain why he used this algorithm?

is it specific way for sin graph? like noise, vibration?

Comment: I don't know why they picked this particular algorithm, but the code is sloppily written and could be improved a lot. The `memset` call is redundant and so is the if-else.

Comment: The algorithm calculates a moving average.

Comment: "is it specific way for sin graph?" --> No.

Comment: @Xaver - it really doesn't.  It tries _incorrectly_ to calculate an average of a block, it is certainly not a _moving_ average.

Comment: If the intent _was_ to calculate a moving average, post a question asking how to do that.

Comment: This idea is something like a rolling average where older signal matters less than newer content.  I used a similar algorithm when doing some java battle bot code that was size constrained.  It means that the bot would react more to newer stimulus than old.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Perhaps, but if that were the intent, you'd hope the code were better commented.   More likely that it is just wrong. It calculates on a finite and fixed number of samples, not a continuous stream.  Your suggestion would better dealt with by an IIR low pass filter in any case.

Comment: Seems like an X-Y problem, you are asking us to explain code that you also admit is incorrect.  Better to ask how to _correctly_ do what the code is _required_ to do.  And by that I don't mean how to calculate an average, because it seems likely that a block-average of a continuous signal is not really what you need.

Comment: What is the value of `SOUND_COUNT`?  What is the sample rate?  What is the bandwidth of the signal?  With that information it would be possible (in Excel even) to simulate the effect of this to see the effect.  If you don't know that information (and it does not look like sample rate is deterministic in this case) then you cannot really know that this does what the originator intended.

Comment: @Clifford SOUND_COUND value is 128, i don't know samplerate. it just work by arduino's analogRead method in for loop, also bandwidth, program need to check periodically noise, vibration average since little time for other system, is IIR best way for check noise, vibration average?

Comment: @Michael Dorgan is this effective calculating noise, vibration?

Comment: It may work adequately but it is not very scientific. Without knowing the signal bandwidth, the noise bandwidth, or a known and accurate sample rate or the cut-off if any anti-alias filter, it is nothing more than empirical. In any event a moving/window average (which is a special case if an FIR filter) would make more sense than this block average. Not least because you will have a result at every sample rather than every 28. You can do low frequency DSP in an Arduino, but it is far from ideal.

Comment: Keep in mind for my example, every byte of outputted code mattered.  So a "good enough" average calculator that only took a couple bytes of code was far superior to a completely correct solution.  My solution handled threat detection cheap and allowed more "bytes" to go towards other parts of my system.  (Robocode in a division where codesize limited entrants.  My code had to be 249 bytes or less.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a flawed attempt at maintaining a cumulative mean.  The error is in believing that:

A<sub>n+1</sub> = (A<sub>n</sub> + s<sub>n</sub>) / 2

when in fact it should be:

A<sub>n+1</sub> = ((A<sub>n</sub> * n) + s) / (n + 1)

However it is computationally simpler to maintain a running sum and generate an average in the usual manner:

S = S + s
A<sub>n</sub> = S / n

It is possible that the intent was to avoid overflow when the sum grows large, but the attempt is mathematically flawed.

To see how wrong this statement is consider:

```
        True 
n   s   Running Avg.    (An + sn) / 2
--------------------------------------
1   20  20              20
2   21  20.5            20.25
3   22  21              20.625
```

In this case however, nothing is done with the intermediate mean value, so you don'e in fact need to maintain a running mean at all. You simply need to accumulate a running sum and calculate the average at the end. For example:

```
      sum = 0 ;
      sound_value = 0 ;
      
      for( int i2 = 0; i2 < SOUND_COUNT; i2++ )
      {
        soundRaw[i2] = analogRead( PIN_ANALOG_IN ) ;
        sum += soundRaw[i2] ;
      }
    
      sound_value = sum / SOUND_COUNT ;
```

In this you do need to make sure that the data type for`sum` can accommodate a value of the maximum `analogRead()` return multiplied by `SOUND_COUNT`.

However you say that this is used for some sort of signal conditioning or processing of both a microphone and an accelerator.  These devices have rather dissimilar bandwidth and dynamics, and it seems rather unlikely that the same filter would suit both. Applying robust DSP techniques such as IIR or FIR filters with suitably calculated coefficients would make a great deal more sense.  You'd also need a suitable fixed sample rate that I am willing to bet is not achieved by simply reading the ADC in a loop with no specific timing

Comment: thanks to answer. i edited it like your example. i'll test it soon. if have problom. i will appliy IIR.

Comment: @herrun You should have probably posted the while sketch.  For an AVR based Arduino ADC, the max sum will be 1023 x 128, so sum will need to be a long (32 bit) integer type.